# Menu inside module configuration

Tags: php, jquery-ui, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm writing a module for presta. I wolud like create a menu inside my module configuration. Something similar to menu that we can see in Stats category (category tree on the left side) Is there any way to generate this via helpers?

If there is no way to generate this menu automatically, then I have different question. How to manually insert into tpl file generated via helpers form elements? And how to write this menu manually (based on bootstrap) in tpl file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the data array to a variable in smarty, then in your tpl file iterate over this array with foreach loop.

```
<ul>
  {foreach from=$datacollection item=curr_id}
  <li>
    id: {$curr_id}<br />
  </li>
  {/foreach}
</ul>
```